# Скрипт для изменения размера изображения. В чем ошибка?

Tags: php

Проблема в следующем: скрипт изменяет размер изображения, но на сайте вместо изображения черный квадрат (именно такого размера который должен быть). В чем ошибка?

```
if (empty($_FILES['fupload']['name'])) {
    //если переменной не существует (пользователь не отправил изображение),то присваиваем ему заранее приготовленную картинку с надписью "нет аватара"
    $avatar = "avatars/net-avatara.jpg"; //можете нарисовать net-avatara.jpg или взять в исходниках
}

else {
    //иначе - загружаем изображение пользователя
    $path_to_90_directory = 'avatars/'; //папка, куда будет загружаться начальная картинка и ее сжатая копия

    if (preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/', $_FILES['fupload']['name'])) //проверка формата исходного изображения
        {
        $filename = $_FILES['fupload']['name'];
        $source   = $_FILES['fupload']['tmp_name'];
        $target   = $path_to_90_directory . $filename;
        move_uploaded_file($source, $target); //загрузка оригинала в папку $path_to_90_directory

        if (preg_match('/[.](GIF)|(gif)$/', $filename)) {
            $im = imagecreatefromgif($path_to_90_directory . $filename); //если оригинал был в формате gif, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
        }
        if (preg_match('/[.](PNG)|(png)$/', $filename)) {
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($path_to_90_directory . $filename); //если оригинал был в формате png, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
        }

        if (preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)$/', $filename)) {
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_to_90_directory . $filename); //если оригинал был в формате jpg, то создаем изображение в этом же формате. Необходимо для последующего сжатия
        }

        //СОЗДАНИЕ КВАДРАТНОГО ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ И ЕГО ПОСЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ СЖАТИЕ ВЗЯТО С САЙТА www.codenet.ru

        // Создание квадрата 90x90
        // dest - результирующее изображение 
        // w - ширина изображения 
        // ratio - коэффициент пропорциональности

        // квадратная 90x90. Можно поставить и другой размер.

        // создаём исходное изображение на основе 
        // исходного файла и определяем его размеры 
        $w_src = imagesx($im); //вычисляем ширину
        $h_src = imagesy($im); //вычисляем высоту изображения

        // создаём пустую квадратную картинку 
        // важно именно truecolor!, иначе будем иметь 8-битный результат 
        $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

        // вырезаем квадратную серединку по x, если фото горизонтальное 
        if ($w_src > $h_src) {
            $w = 800;
            $h = 534;
            imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, round((max($w_src, $h_src) - min($w_src, $h_src)) / 2), 0, $w, $h, min($w_src, $h_src), min($w_src, $h_src));
            $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        }

        // вырезаем квадратную верхушку по y, 
        // если фото вертикальное (хотя можно тоже серединку) 
        if ($w_src < $h_src) {
            $w = 532;
            $h = 800;
            imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, min($w_src, $h_src), min($w_src, $h_src));
            $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        }

        // квадратная картинка масштабируется без вырезок 
        if ($w_src == $h_src) {
            $w = 800;
            $h = 534;
            imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_src, $w_src);
            $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        }

        $dat  = date();
        $date = time(); //вычисляем время в настоящий момент.
        imagejpeg($dest, $path_to_90_directory . $_POST["login"] . $dat . $date . "1.jpg"); //сохраняем изображение формата jpg в нужную папку, именем будет текущее время. Сделано, чтобы у аватаров не было одинаковых имен.

        //почему именно jpg? Он занимает очень мало места + уничтожается анимирование gif изображения, которое отвлекает пользователя. Не очень приятно читать его комментарий, когда краем глаза замечаешь какое-то движение.

        $avatar = $path_to_90_directory . $_POST["login"] . $dat . $date . "1.jpg"; //заносим в переменную путь до аватара.

        $delfull = $path_to_90_directory . $filename;
        unlink($delfull); //удаляем оригинал загруженного изображения, он нам больше не нужен. Задачей было - получить миниатюру.
    } else {
        //в случае несоответствия формата, выдаем соответствующее сообщение

        exit("Аватар должен быть в формате <strong>JPG,GIF или PNG</strong>"); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

    }
    //конец процесса загрузки и присвоения переменной $avatar адреса загруженной авы
}
```

Comment: @LordyGL, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут очевидная ошибка:

```
imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, round((max($w_src, $h_src) - min($w_src, $h_src)) / 2), 0, $w, $h, min($w_src, $h_src), min($w_src, $h_src));
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
```

а должно быть наоборот

```
$dest = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopyresampled($dest, $im, 0, 0, round((max($w_src, $h_src) - min($w_src, $h_src)) / 2), 0, $w, $h, min($w_src, $h_src), min($w_src, $h_src));
```

то есть сначала создаём изображение а потом в него копируем область